# ckeditor adds \r\n after any paragraph with mysql real escape string and PDO

Tags: pdo, mysql-real-escape-string

i was using the normal way to connect to the database and fetch data using mysql real escape string and i didn't face any erros but after moving to PDO I'm facing a problem which is adding  \r\n to the end of the text in ckeditor here's the code

```
$home = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['home']);
$about = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['about']);
$id = '1';
$stmt = $db->prepare("update pages set home = :home, about = :about where ID = :id");
$stmt->bindParam(':home',$home);
$stmt->bindParam(':about',$about);
$stmt->bindParam(':id',$id);
$stmt->execute();
```

using this code to display data inside ckeditor

```
<textarea name="home" id="editor1" class="ckeditor"><?=$row['home']?></textarea><script>
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
</script>
```

I've added this line to ckeditor config file but the same result

```
config.FormatOutput = false ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all PDO and mysql should not be mix.

Using pdo you don't need to escape anything, that's the whole point of [**prepared statement**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

so just use the variables directly:

```
$home = $_REQUEST['home'];
$about = $_REQUEST['about'];
...
```